# Motherboard stuck on cpu initialization screen

Tags: motherboard, troubleshooting

I recently just bought a supermicro x11srm-vf motherboard and an intel Xeon w-2123 processor, and I've been having trouble starting it up. Whenever I turn it on, it gets stuck on a screen that says "PEI--CPU Initialization" and the motherboard beeps 3 times. I couldn't find anything in the manual about a beep code for it, and I haven't found any answers researching it. Ive plugged in all the required power plugs, and I've also taken out the memory and unplugged the hard drive in case that had to do with it. I've also double checked that I put the cpu in the correct way. Does this mean that any of my components are broken or incompatible?

Comment: Your RAM is the culprit. Replace the kit(s) and retest.

Comment: I just tried it with the ram (I have 2x16 ddr4 2666 mhz), and I placed it where the manual said to. I tried it with just one and with both, but neither worked. Based on what I read in the manual, it should be compatible (speed, gb, number of ram sticks). Does the server motherboard require server ram?

Answer (score 1):

From:

https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/X11SRM-VF

Ram:

- Up to 256GB **ECC** RDIMM, DDR4-2933MHz; Up to 512GB **ECC** LRDIMM, DDR4-2933MHz, in 4 DIMM slots

**Use ECC RAM**.  Less common, and more expensive, than typical consumer non-ECC RAM.

ECC RAM is a Random Access Memory module with built-in hardware-level error correction circuitry.  Most often used in server applications (afaik).

Also RAM population sequence is important (Page 30 of the Motherboard manual):
[image]

Comment: ECC RAM is often referred to as 'Server RAM'.  But I find the term 'Server RAM' to be ambiguous.